# golang with compile error: undefined: bytes in bytes.Buffer

Tags: go

I defined a struct as below, but always get the build error: “undefined: bytes in bytes.Buffer”

```
type test struct {
    id       int64
    Content    []byte
    Buffer     *bytes.Buffer
}
```

Comment: Also, make sure you actually want a pointer to `bytes.Buffer`. That struct has some "scratch space" internally, which is used to avoid unneeded allocations for small buffers.

Comment: I faced the same issue. The problem was that I had declared a variable name `bytes`!

Answer (score 19):

You forgot about import statement.

```
import "bytes"
```